# Terminal icon appearing too large in title bar (Glitch) in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, icons

For some odd reason I have a portion of the terminal dock/taskbar icon appearing on various title bars (see pic below). I installed Ubuntu on my laptop 2 days ago. This issue was not present during the first day, but started on the second. It seems like the icon is just too large, but I honestly do not ever remember changing any such settings.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (64-bit) on an HP laptop. Please let me know if I should include any other system information.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happened to me as well. Reading through the submitted bug report mentioned in the above answers I noticed one of the preconditions for this bug to happen was that gnome-icon-theme package was not installed.

Indeed, my system did not have that package, and after installing it with:

```
> sudo apt install gnome-icon-theme
```

The icon appeared with the correct size in the menu bar.

Comment: This solved the issue (that I hadn't resolved since I posted this question over a year ago!). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a broken patch applied downstream by Ubuntu, reported at [Launchpad bug 1770507](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1770507). Please ping and urge the developers over there to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

If it is disturbing, you can simply hide icons on window title by turning on Top Bar -> Application Menu of genome tweak tool. It will move icon to main titlebar instead

[image]

Hope it helps!